# How to implement movement speed of object correctly?

Tags: android, graphics, physics

So I am coing an android game and have managed to make a ball roll over the screen in the direction you tilt your phone. However I would like to make the ball roll faster the more you tilt your screen.

But what is the best way to implement this? Taking bigger steps is obv not good, it makes collisions hard to calculate. I want to move more steps per second instead.

So lets say you have a tiled board and you implement speed as tiles/millisecond. But that is problematic also speed will not be continous. You'd perhaps move 1 step every 10th time in a loop instead of every time in the loop. So you would move, then be still, then move, etc instead of continously moving. But maybe that is as good as it gets?

So this problem applies generally for any kind if computer graphics I guess. How do you implement this the best way? I'm specifically interested in what applies to Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural way of implementing speed and position problems is to have position calculated with the speed that way :

```
position = speed * dt
```

with dt constant, adapted for your implementation.

So basically the natural way is to increase the step. You say it's obviously bad for collision detection but with a limited speed and a small dt I don't really see why.

Comment: dt is the time step. It will heavily depend on your implementation and is best to be chosen by trial and error. A more complex and detailed answer can be found here : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49048/smooth-sprite-movement-dont-add-velocity-to-position